# Are Gromov-hyperbolic groups roughly starlike?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

Given a Cayley graph of a finitely generated Gromov-hyperbolic group $G$, does there exists $R>0$ such that every element $g \in G$ is at most distance $R$ away from a geodesic ray starting at identity $e$?

Comment: Sorry, I realized that this question was already answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324796/criterion-for-visuality-of-hyperbolic-spaces?rq=1#).